# When finding the integral presented below, why do we substitute $u=2x$ rather than $u=1+4 x^{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

So in the integral I am cognisant that we perform u subsitution, my query is why is

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d x}{1+4 x^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u=2 x
\end{equation}

but not

\begin{equation}
u=1+4 x^{2}
\end{equation}

Performing the differential when u=2x we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{d u}{d x}=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d u}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

From here what would be the u subsitution in the original integral?

\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d u}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1+4 x^{2}}dx
\end{equation}

Comment: Don't forget the variable of integration. You have so far that $\int \frac{dx}{1+4x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{1+4x^2}$. Make sure the integral is in terms of $u$ entirely, not $x$, before you proceed.

Comment: \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^{2}+1} d u
\end{equation}  so like this?

Comment: @AMN Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to realize why the substitution $u = 2x$ works:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + 4x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(2x)}{1 + (2x)^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1 + u^{2}} = \frac{\arctan(u)}{2} + c = \frac{\arctan(2x)}{2} + c
\end{align*}

If you make the change of variable $u = 1 + 2x^{2}$, you should get
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + 4x^{2}} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(x(u)\right)}{u}
\end{align*}

where $$x(u) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{u - 1}{2}}$$

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh that's genius it's the inverse trigonometric function in the question! and because 2x multiplied by 2x gives us 4x squared so we just replace the square number with 2x and then we substitute it in. I'll give some more practice on this type of integration thank you so much.

Comment: @AMN You are welcome! I am glad I could help.